# Figuring out what Heroku resources I need for a give site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

What is the best way to get a ballpark idea of what kind of resources an application needs if it is running on Heroku (how many dynos and what db plan you should be running)?

My non-technical friend had his site built in rails and it is currently being hosted on Linode by the shop that built the app. They aren't providing the support he was hoping for, and is interested in having me move it over to Heroku, but we are trying to get an idea of how much more that is going to cost him. I tried contacting the dev shop directly to find out what the current instance is running on, but they aren't getting back to me.

I have access to their analytics, and the current repo, so from this can I glean what kind of initial setup we are probably going to need, and if so what should I be looking for? I realize that this is very situation dependent and not an easy question to answer, but any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[dyno-blitzer](https://github.com/kowsik/dyno-blitzer) will help you find out how many dynos you'll need to support 1,000 users, but there are a lot of questions you need to answer in order to try and ballpark what you'll need with Heroku:

- How big is the database right now? How fast is it growing?
- How many users do you need to support? If you only need 5, the numbers dyno-blitzer gives you probably won't be anywhere near what you need.
- How much delayed processing work is being done?
- What sort of things does the app need that have to be provided through add-ons with Heroku?

Once you know these, you should be able to get a rough ballpark, but it won't be laser accurate - this will heavily depend on the app and exactly what it's doing.